# AngularJS - ngModel conflicts with custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

I have this html:

```
<select id="mainVideo" class="form-control" required-select
      ng-model="qtTestData.mainVideo"
      ng-options="mainVideo for mainVideo in mainVideoSources"
      ng-change="getSelectedData(qtTestDataBuffer,'mainVideo', qtTestData.mainVideo)"
      name="mainVideo"
      ng-required="true">
</select>
```

The function **getSelectedData()** takes 3 arguments, and 3rd is ngModel.
Everything works if I do not use my custom directive **required-select**.
My directive:

```
App.directive('requiredSelect', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
        ngModel.$validators.requiredSelect = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
            var value = modelValue || viewValue;
            var requiredSelect = 'Please, select a value'; //TBD.. select first ngOption
            return value != requiredSelect;
        };
    }
};
```

});

If I include **required-select** directive into HTML, my ngModel becomes `qtTestData.mainVideo == undefined` by default and as result I have crashes...
Looks like ngModel has been overwritten by the directive...

Does someone know how to fix it?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your directive, If you never set `$scope.qtTestData.mainVideo` it will automatically be `undefined`. Set it first to some default value, and your code will just work.

```
.controller('YourController', function($scope){
    $scope.mainVideoSources = [
        'Please, select a value',
        'A',
        'B'
    ];
    $scope.qtTestData = {
        mainVideo: 'Please, select a value'
    };

});
```

Comment: I have predefined data from the server (almost the same structure as you have described).

Comment: I have found the problem. It works if I directly define `$scope.qtTestData = { mainVideo: 'Please, select a value' };` As in your example. But if I am using a link `$scope.qtTestData = { mainVideo: $scope.mainVideoSourses[0] };` I am getting **undefined** for `ngModel` (if directive is included, without it works) But, if I select another value `ngModel` will pass **undefined** Do you know why? Thanks,

Comment: Make sure you set `qtTestData = { mainVideo: ... ` after `scope.mainVideoSources[0]` defined. In case you take the data from server, just make sure the scope is updated by running `$apply`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change a syntax of directive requiring, instead of this:

```
require: 'ngModel',
```

try this:

```
require: '^ngModel',
```

This example may be useful for you [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/oQyUdxKuCyz4gtUUrNSG?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed by removing

```
ng-required="true"
```

from the element where custom directive is applied.
As I understand, we should not use `ng-required="true"` with `$validators` on one element